# Ruby Stubbing Best Practices for Time Consuming Operation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

Curious about best practices for testing a particular situation.

I have a model that requires some time consuming operations to set up- reaching out to external services, parsing, kernel stuff, etc. One particular part of the set up is basically optional- I'd like to check that it's been run, but the result won't matter for almost all tests.

This model is used as input to many other classes, so I want to avoid a lengthy test suite and overbearing setup for a relatively unimportant step.

I'd like to know if this covers my bases, or if I'm going about this all wrong.

Currently, I am:

1. Stubbing out the operation globally

   ```
       config.before(:each) do
         LongOperation.any_instance.stub(:the_operation)
       end
   ```
2. Testing that it gets called in my background job

code:

```
    class BackgroundSetupWorker
      def perform
        LongOperation.the_operation
      end
    end
```

and test:

```
    LongOperation.should_receive(:the_operation)
```

3. Unit testing the long-running operation

```
    before(:each) do
      LongOperation.unstub(:the_operation)
    end

    it "works preoperly" do
      expect(LongOperation.the_operation).to ...
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the ideal thing would be to take the LongOperation class as a param so you can switch it out in the tests however you like.

```
class BackgroundSetupWorker
  def initialize(op_provider = LongOperation)
    @op_provider = op_provider
  end

  def perform
    @op_provider.the_operation
  end
end

#in spec
describe BackgroundSetupWorker do
  let(:op_provider){ double(the_operation: nil) }
  subject(:worker){ BackgroundSetupWorker.new(op_provider) }

  it 'should call op_provider' do  
    worker.perform

    expect(op_provider).to have_received(:the_operation)
  end
end
```